# What are the available options of using AWS SES with third-party encryption of email body?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, encryption, amazon-ses

I am trying to search for options that can provide end to end encryption of email content and use AWS SES as SMTP Relay.
One option is to use SES provided PGP Encryption, but I want to explore third-party options having the same objective.
I was able to find Gmail SMTP Relay third-party vendors like PauBox, but will like to keep SMTP service to SES.
Can anyone help on such third-parties compatible with AWS SES?

Comment: One option you have is to use AWS KMS as discussed here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-ses.html

Comment: @smac2020 This is used for encryption of received email messages with KMS before storing it to S3.
I need to send emails with encrypted body content.